# Solve $a^3 -b^3 -c^3=3abc, a^2=2(b+c)$ in natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve $a^3 -b^3 -c^3=3abc, a^2=2(b+c)$ in natural numbers.

Substituting $a=\sqrt{2(b+c)}$ in the cubic equation, we get:
$2\sqrt{2}(b+c)^{\frac{3}{2}} - b^3 -c^3 = 3\sqrt{2(b+c)}bc$
$2\sqrt{2}(b+c)\sqrt{b+c} - b^3 -c^3 = 3\sqrt{2(b+c)}bc$

Not able to proceed further, although I think that binomial expansion of $\sqrt{b+c}$ can yield some more steps. But, am confused about applying that too.

Comment: $a=2, b=c=1$ works.

Comment: @vadim123 Do you want to suggest that an algebraic approach is not possible, at least at my beginner level.

Comment: I'm not making a suggestion, just pointing out a solution I found, which might help others.

Comment: Try reducing the equation mod 3 and mod 2 first to see what modular information you can get. Sometimes this is enough and more pleasant than huge square roots.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I request you to post an answer, as am not as comfortable with congruence arithmetic, as might be needed.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Some hint to reducing equation using $\mod 2 \mod 3$, as I never did like that before. I hope it is for finding residue for the smallest modulo even and odd classes, as $3=(2n+1)$. If not an answer, then a hint.

Comment: @jitender Here mod $3$ by Fermat's theorem ($x^3\equiv x$ mod $3$ for all $x$) you would get $a\equiv b+c$ mod 3, therefore $b+c=a+3K$ for some $K$, This is weaker than the given answers, in this case. You would still need to work a little bit to get to the solution.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks a lot, lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz & = x^3+y^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+z^3-3xyz-3x^2y-3xy^2 \\
& =(x+y)^3+z^3-3xy(x+y+z)\\
&= (x+y+z)((x+y)^2+z^2-(x+y)z)-3xy(x+y+z) \\ & =(x+y+z)(x^2+2xy+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-3xy) \\ & =(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)\end{align}

Therefore, for distinct $x,y $ and $z$; $$
x^3+y^3+x^3=3xyz \implies x+y+z=0$$ Notice that your equation can rewritten as  $$(a)^3+(-b)^3+(-c)^3=3 (a) (-b)(-c)$$

$$\implies a-b-c=0$$

Substitute $a=b+c$ in your second equation,

$$ 
a^2=2(b+c) \implies (b+c)^2=2(b+c) \implies b+c=2$$

So finally , we've $a=2$ and $b+c=2$.

So the only natural solution to these equations is  $\color{blue}{(a,b,c)=(2,1,1)}$.

Comment: Please elaborate how $0=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz \implies x+y+z=0$.

Comment: $x$, $y$, $z$ need not be distinct here

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier Is this a mandatory condition, or based on symmetry, or just obvious.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Remember that $x,y$ and $z$ aren't $a,b$ and $c$, instead $x=a, y=-b $ and $z=-c$. And since $a,b,c \in \Bbb N$, $a=-b$ is impossible.

Comment: @jitender See my edit.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
$$0=a^3-b^3-c^3-3abc = \frac12(a-b-c)[(a+b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c+a)^2]$$
So we have two cases:
Case 1:
$a=b+c \implies a^2=2a \implies a \in \{0, 2\}$.
You should be able to fnd out $b+c$ bounded in this case...

OR Case 2:
$a+b=b-c=c+a=0$, which again reduces cases considerably among natural numbers.

Comment: $0$ isn't natural number... or is it?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thats up for debate, not a debate I want to enter into.  In either case, the approach leads to all solutions.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what you found wrong above?

Comment: So you live at a place, where $0 \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Did you downvote for that?  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number  Both definitions can be used.  In either case my approach works.

Comment: No I didn't. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}
{}{}{}$

Comment: Lot's of people live in a place where $0 \in \mathbb N$.  The rent is slightly higher but sometimes the view is really nice.